# Why is the Azure TodoList giving me an 500 internal server error?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to make an app via xamarin.forms with an Azure Backend(Via Visual Studio for Mac)

I followed the tutorial to setup this environment ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started )

I created an app inside the azure web platform, then I downloaded the new project that's pre-configured by Azure.

But when I'm running the app and adding a todo list item, I get a `MobileserviceInvalidOperationException`:

> Internal Server error (error code: 500)

This is what's getting sent:

[image: Debugging]

Comment: Are you using "http" or "https"? Make sure Authentication is turned off. Second thing to check is the date/time on your device/emulator. That can cause problems too

Comment: Dear, How can I check both of those things? @YuriS I thought azure is using https standard.

Comment: 1. when you use client you have to provide connection string. Is it https? 2.Go to Azure website and check app authenticaton 3. Check date/time on emulator

Comment: @YuriS I checked it, it's indeed https, the app authentication is off and the date and time is correct at  the minute.. Is there any other option, I really want to skip the 500 error, so I can make an app :(

Comment: is your  internet connection enabled on phone? Are you using emulator or real phone?

Comment: If you use android check INTERNET permissions in your app Manifest. Do you get more details inside 500 error? Do you have correct key in your MobileClient?

Comment: I'm using an emulator, don't know how I can get it running on my real iPhone. I did check that permission and turned it on, but that didn't help. How can I get more inside the 500 error? I want to thank you that you want to help thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135126/discussion-between-royvano-and-yuri-s).